# How Do I Create an 'OR' Condition Using the ActiveRecord Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given the following code which creates an `and` condition, how do I make it create an `or` condition instead?

```
Country.first(:conditions=>{:media_code=>country_code, :code=>country_code})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with array style conditions:

```
Country.first(:conditions => ["media_code = :code or code = :code", {:code => country_code}])
```